# Have image and text as one box

Tags: css, flexbox

So im trying to make a flexbox which displays a countrys flag and the language name next to it. The problem i ran into was that the text and picture are treated individually and end up seperated if they are at the end of the box. Is there a way to make one flag with its language into one box and the same for the others, so that the flag and corresponding language are always together?

This is my code so far:

```css
#size {
  width: 105px;
  height: 60px;
  flex-basis: 10%;
}

.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img src="Flag/BU.png" id="size"><a>България</a>
  <img src="Flag/CH.png" id="size"><a>中国人</a>
  <img src="Flag/FR.png" id="size"><a>Francaise</a>
  <img src="Flag/GER.png" id="size"><a>Deutsch</a>
  <img src="Flag/HU.png" id="size"><a>Magyar</a>
  <img src="Flag/IN.png" id="size"><a>हिंदी</a>
  <img src="Flag/JA.png" id="size"><a>日本</a>
  <img src="Flag/SK.png" id="size"><a>한국인</a>
  <img src="Flag/SP.png" id="size"><a>Español</a>
  <img src="Flag/UK.png" id="size"><a>English</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need to wrap the `<img>` and `<a>` elements in a common parent. I don't think there's any way to get flexbox to treat two child elements as one.

Comment: What's the point of those `a` elements to begin with? If clicking them is supposed to trigger some sort of language selection, then I would expect clicking on the image to achieve the same thing ... so why are the images not _inside_ those `a` to begin with?

Comment: do the <img> and <a> element in a <div> then are your flag and flagname always together

Comment: Or you can put image inside `a` element making image and text both as links

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example to use the grid system instead of flexbox

```css
#size {
    width: 105px;
    height: 60px;
    flex-basis: 10%;
    
}

.grid-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <img src="Flag/BU.png" id="size"><a>България</a>
    <img src="Flag/CH.png" id="size"><a>中国人</a>
    <img src="Flag/FR.png" id="size"><a>Francaise</a>
    <img src="Flag/GER.png" id="size"><a>Deutsch</a>
    <img src="Flag/HU.png" id="size"><a>Magyar</a>
    <img src="Flag/IN.png" id="size"><a>हिंदी</a>
    <img src="Flag/JA.png" id="size"><a>日本</a>
    <img src="Flag/SK.png" id="size"><a>한국인</a>
    <img src="Flag/SP.png" id="size"><a>Español</a>
    <img src="Flag/UK.png" id="size"><a>English</a>
</div>
```